# Can't install azure cli extension : Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='objects.githubusercontent.com', port=443)

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops

Trying to install the Azure Devops CLI Extension

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/cli/?view=azure-devops

az extension add --name azure-devops
is the command I run

I get the following error message

Error Message I have tried

git config http.sslVerify "false"
I've tried to do multiple azure cli and powershell commands

I've set my context with

Set-AzContext -Subscription "xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
I don't understand what the issue is here.

I've tried running the commands with and without the VPN ( I use Pulse VPN for reference)

I've tried setting powershell's execution policy to Undefined

**Set-ExecutionPolicy -ExecutionPolicy Undefined -Scope CurrentUser**
If someone could please let me know their thoughts on the specific error:

Please ensure you have network connection. Error detail: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='objects.githubusercontent.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /github-production-release-asset-2e65be/107708057/665228bd-d0c3-4865-b029-624cbc247ca1?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIWNJYAX4CSVEH53A%2F20220701%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20220701T163308Z&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Signature=dd9381d3d71deeb228b151ec41140e8238f425ca9bf2882889c6bc9592c782e6&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&actor_id=0&key_id=0&repo_id=107708057&response-content-disposition=attachment%3B%20filename%3Dazure_devops-0.25.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

Answer (score 0):

Normally, when executing the command line "**`az extension add --name azure-devops`**", it will go to the [**Azure DevOps CLI Extension GitHub Repo**](https://github.com/Azure/azure-devops-cli-extension) to download the latest release of the extension.

You can try to manually open the **Azure DevOps CLI Extension GitHub Repo** and download the extension on your browser:

- If you also cannot manually access the GitHub Repo and download the extension, check whether there is any networking restriction or firewall set on your machine and the current network.
- If you can manually access the GitHub Repo and download the extension, try to manually install the extension on your machine.

Comment: Hi @saedarm, I have not heard from you for a long time. whether you have viewed my answer? Are the explanations in my answer helpful for you?
As explained in my answer, you need to check whether there is any networking restriction or firewall set on your machine and the current network.